# Open source проекты для распознавания чисел на Android

Tags: android, java

К одному android-приложению хотелось бы прикрутить распознавание чисел с фотографии. Существуют ли какие-то свободные наработки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) же.